# AS3 Stop Dragging all items

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function that recognizes the ESC key being pressed. At which point, I want to stop dragging all items.

I"ve tried this.stopDrag() but it wont override the MOUSE_DOWN event.

It there a way to force it to "drop" the item being dragged?

Thanks

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, escapeKeyDown);

function escapeKeyDown(event : KeyboardEvent):void {
if (event.keyCode == 27) {
    trace("ESC");
    this.stopDrag();
}
}
```

Comment: "All items" -- you're only calling `stopDrag()` on one item (whatever `this` is), since that event listener only fires once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a global array of all your dragging DisplayObjects:

```
static var CURRENT_DRAGGING_ITEMS:Array = [];
```

Then whenever you call startDrag on anything, add it to the array.

```
function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    event.target.startDrag();
    CURRENT_DRAGGING_ITEMS.push(event.target);
}
```

Then when you hit ESC, just loop through the array, calling stopDrag on all items, and removing them from the array.

```
function escapeKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
    var targetIndex:uint = CURRENT_DRAGGING_ITEMS.indexOf(event.target);
    CURRENT_DRAGGING_ITEMS.splice(targetIndex, 1);
}
```

Make sure you also remove the dragging item from the array when you call stopDrag on it from anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I've tried the event.target.stopDrag(); but I get the following error:  Error #1069: Property startDrag not found on flash.display.Stage and there is no default value.
 at flightCellMaker_fla::MainTimeline/escapeKeyDown()

Comment: Just tried stopDrag(); on it's own and this did the trick. Thanks for your help!